# Border and Grid in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I'm new in bootstrap and just trying to understand how the grid line works and making boxes on it. I don't know why does the style doesn't take effect.
Here is my code:

```
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 main ">
        <h2>Welcome to Dashboard!</h2>
      </div>

     <div class="col-md-4 sidebar style="background-color: #dedef8;box-shadow:inset 1px -1px 1px #444, inset -1px 1px 1px #444; ">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid, you should close class attribute quote, and add missing `</div>` tag. After all you also make sure that total sum of columns is exactly 12 per row. Something like this maybe:

```
<div id="content" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 sidebar">
            <h2>Sidebar</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8 main ">
            <h2>Welcome to Dashboard!</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo 1: http://plnkr.co/edit/YpfBDxXHrmGslzMUjEVh?p=preview

Here `col-xs-4` + `col-xs-8` fills 12 column row. `col-xs-` styles are effective starting from extra small dimensions and higher. You can of course make it more sophisticated, for example you want sidebar to take whole row pushing main content below it for xs devises:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 sidebar">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 main">
        <h2>Welcome to Dashboard!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo 2: http://plnkr.co/edit/YpfBDxXHrmGslzMUjEVh?p=preview

Comment: Now it works!, I just forgot to close the class. Thank you so much!. :)